# Calling jQuery function located in a external file

Tags: jquery

I have a function addUIComponents() which in debug.js which adds dynamic components to displayComponents.jsp. Now, addUIComponents() is called in another js file which checks whether or not this function is required. 
This is debug.js file:

```
function addUIComponents(){
alert("In addUIComponents");
//some work
}
```

This is in another.js

```
var debugMode = true;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(debugMode == true) {
            addUIComponents();
        }
    });
```

My problem is that addUIComponents() is not being called. I can say this as the alert is not shown. Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

In your debug.js file, all you need is:

```
function addUIComponents() {
    alert("In addUIComponents");
    //some work
}
```

Make sure both .js files are included, and you should be good to go!

Comment: Any errors in the console, I'm assuming it says something like `addUIComponents is undefined`